# R: Why does read.table stop reading a file?

Tags: r

I have a file, called `genes.txt`, which I'd like to become a data.frame. It's got a lot of lines, each line has three, tab delimited fields:

```
mike$ wc -l genes.txt
   42476 genes.txt
```

I'd like to read this file into a data.frame in R. I use the command read.table, like this:

```
genes = read.table(
    genes_file, 
    sep="\t", 
    na.strings="-", 
    fill=TRUE,
    col.names=c("GeneSymbol","synonyms","description")
)
```

Which seems to work fine, where `genes_file` points at `genes.txt`. However, the number of lines in my data.frame is significantly less than the number of lines in my text file:

```
> nrow(genes)
[1] 27896
```

and things I can find in the text file:

```
mike$ grep "SELL" genes.txt 
SELL    CD62L|LAM1|LECAM1|LEU8|LNHR|LSEL|LYAM1|PLNHR|TQ1    selectin L
```

don't seem to be in the data.frame

```
> grep("SELL",genes$GeneSymbol)
integer(0)
```

it turns out that

```
genes = read.delim(
    genes_file,
    header=FALSE,
    na.strings="-",
    fill=TRUE,
    col.names=c("GeneSymbol","synonyms","description"),
)
```

works just fine. Why does read.delim work when read.table not?

If it's of use, you can recreate `genes.txt` using the following commands which you should run from a command line

```
curl -O ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/DATA/gene_info.gz
gzip -cd gene_info.gz | awk -Ft '$1==9606{print $3 "\t" $5 "\t" $9}' > genes.txt
```

be warned, though, that gene_info.gz is 101MBish.

Comment: Is there by chance anything special at line 27897 that could break the import? I cannot download the file right now, I will try later if you haven't received an answer yet.

Comment: Not that I can see! It turns out that read.delim works fine, so this is slightly less annoying than it was. I've edited the question quite heavily (apologies to the 11 people that read it within the first 4 minutes of it going up) to rephrase the question to why does read.delim work when read.table fails?

Comment: I haven't looked at the file but quoting and comments are two common ways for things to break.  For example, read.table treats '#' as a comment character which is inappropriate for many files.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With read.table one of the default quote characters is the single quote.  I'm guessing you have some unmatched single quotes in your description field and all the data between single quotes is being pooled together into one entry.

With read.delim the defualt quote character is the double quote and thus this isn't a problem.

Specify your quote character and you should be all set.

```
> genes<-read.table("genes.txt",sep="\t",quote="\"",na.strings="-",fill=TRUE, col.names=c("GeneSymbol","synonyms","description"))
> nrow(genes)
[1] 42476
```

Comment: thanks! I expect that I should have noticed my final entry was huge! The joys of the learning curve...

Comment: Join the Church of The Learning Curve. :)

Comment: Another option (which I used) is to set quote = "" and simply remove quotes. Note that you'll be more likely to get this problem *silently* if you use fill = TRUE.