# reading big data file using cbc.read.table

Tags: r

I'm trying to read a giant DF `cbc.read.table`:

```
my.df <- cbc.read.table("df.csv",sep = ";", header =F)
```

This is what I get:

```
Error in cbc.read.table("2012Q2.csv", sep = "|", header = F) : 
No rows to read
```

The wd is set correctly. Inprinciple it works using read.table, just that it doesn't read in all lines (about two million)

Has anybody an idea what I can do about this?

SOLUTION:
Hi again, the following thread helped me out:
[R: Why does read.table stop reading a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016333/r-why-does-read-table-stop-reading-a-file)

The problem was caused by quotation marks, probably because some of them were not closing. I simply used an editor and deleted all double and single quotation marks as well as all hash marks. It's working now.

@Anthony: Thanks for your question. I noticed that the problem did not occur in the first three lines which is why I got idea that it's an issue with the file. Thanks!

Paul

Comment: can you provide the first three rows of "df.csv"?

Comment: @Anthony: Thanks for your question. I noticed that the problem did not occur in the first three lines. I found the problem and a solution which I added to my question. Thank you!