# read.table imports less rows than in the .txt file

Tags: r

I've been trying to import a text file that has 878847 records.  When I run `read.table` the resulting dataset only has 403681 observations.  Does anyone know a way to fix this, or a work around?
The .txt file was a copy of some data in an .xls file (which is just a pain to import so I didn't bother)

`read <- read.table(file="myfile.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t", fill=TRUE)`

Any help on this would be appreciated (I need this for work!)

many thanks

Comment: The issue lays probably in the separator. Do you have the right number of columns ? And are they filled properly ?

Comment: I'm concerned that you have `fill=T`. Did you expect the rows to have have different numbers of columns? Do you possible have apostrophes in the data? Maybe set `quote="\"". Or maybe you have `#` symbols in the data? You can try setting `comment=""`

Comment: not all fields will be complete, there will be spaces, thats why I used fill=T.  Pretty sure it's tab delimited, its just a copy and paste from a spreadhseet

Comment: there are email addresses in the data so that could be causing issues with strange characters

Comment: hard to say if we can't see it. Another option would be to save from spreadsheet to csv and then use `read.csv()`. Just be sure to use a separator not in the data.

Comment: quote="\"" increased observations to 584000... must be the dodgy characters in the file

Comment: Since you know at what line the reading terminates, try `readLines(file, skip=n)` to pull in the lines of interest.

Comment: there are commas in the data, I may try ~ or something

Comment: ahaaa! I used `quote=""` and `comment.char=""` this solved the issue.  Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: As the others commented, there are probably characters in the file that are interpreted as quotes or comments. Look at the last line that *was* read (using `tail`), find that in the original txt file.  look for problematic characters in this or the next line, address the problem, and repeat the process until you have read the whole file.

Comment: that's a really good tip, I'll use that for debugging in future

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, so it may be of help to future users.

Comment: I was unable to do that because it was less than 8 hours since posting and I'm only a bronze user

Comment: I think this is the answer you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016333/r-why-does-read-table-stop-reading-a-file